# In which deployment mode can we "Not" add nodes to a cluster in Apache Spark 2.3.1

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, cluster-computing, worker

In which deployment mode can we **Not** add Nodes/workers to a cluster in Apache Spark 2.3.1

1.Spark Standalone
2.Mesos
3.Kubernetes
4.Yarn
5.Local Mode

i have installed Apache Spark 2.3.1 on my machine and have run it in Local Mode

in Local Mode can we add Nodes/workers to Apache Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When master is Local, your program will run on single machine that is your edge node.
To run it in distributed environment i.e. on cluster you need to select master as "Yarn".

When deployment mode is "client" (default) your edge node will become the master (where driver program will run).
When deployment mode is "cluster", any of the healthy node from the cluster becomes master

Comment: So Basically in Local Mode and when deployment mode is client ,i will not be able to add slave/worker in my environment?